# How to avoid same modules duplication Webpack bundling?

Tags: javascript, webpack, node-modules, bundling-and-minification, laravel-mix

I use laravel-mix (including webpack) to bundle JS files.
Using BundleAnalyzerPlugin I found that my output file includes more than one copy of JQuery lib which boosts the output file size.

It seams several modules includes JQuery by themselves.

Any ideas how to avoid this and remove all redundant jquery inclusions?

(UPDATED with more info)

[Image of Bundle analyzer output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGEz4.jpg)

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

mix.js('resources/assets/js/admin.js', 'public/js')

mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ // Added as a suggestion. Makes no difference
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ],
});
```

**admin.js**

```
import 'jquery'
import 'toastr'
```

Comment: We need your `webpack.mix.js` config file

Comment: @RuChernChong I've updated the question with more information (including a copy of webpack.mix.js)

Answer (score 0):

`import 'jquery'` in your entry file and add the below block to your webpack.config

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      '$': 'jquery',
      'jQuery': 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
]
```

Refer: [Webpack Provide Plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks, tried. but didn't help. I've updated the question with more information.

Comment: How about using webpack externals for jQuery?

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: It's probably a workaround. But as I understand it will be excluded from bundle, while I still need the lib to be included once.

Comment: It's not a workaround. The way it works is that webpack will exclude the `require` of jquery assuming its required somewhere else or available globally.

Comment: I mean this is potential workaround in our case. :) As in this case we need to put jquery in external <script src="..."> call. However I'm looking for a way to still bundle it, but only once, rather then moving it out of bundle completely.

Comment: You can still bundle by including jquery in your entry file and use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader to expose jquery globally.